# F# - type must be defined above where it is used

Tags: .net, f#

I have an `F#` file with the types `MyUIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and `NewListing` defined:

```
[<Register ("MyUIImagePickerControllerDelegate")>]
type MyUIImagePickerControllerDelegate() as x = 
   inherit UIImagePickerControllerDelegate ()

let mutable parentView : UIViewController = null

member this.GetSelectedImage
    with get() = selectedImage
    and set(value) = selectedImage <- value

member this.GetParentView 
    with get() = parentView 
    and set(value) = (
        parentView <- value
    )

override x.FinishedPickingImage(controller : UIImagePickerController, image : UIImage, dict : NSDictionary) = 
    let chosenImage = image
    (parentView :?> NewListing).GetIm1.Image <- chosenImage
    parentView.DismissModalViewController(true)

[<Register ("NewListing")>]
type NewListing (handle:IntPtr) as this = 
    inherit UIViewController (handle)   

    override x.ViewDidLoad () =
        base.ViewDidLoad ()

        let del = new MyUIImagePickerControllerDelegate()
        del.GetParentView <- x
```

The problem is these two lines:

```
(parentView :?> NewListing).GetIm1.Image <- chosenImage
```

and:

```
let del = new MyUIImagePickerControllerDelegate()
```

as you can see I am using the `NewListing` inside the `MyUIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and the `MyUIImagePickerControllerDelegate` inside `NewListing`. Due to `F#` requiring all types used later on in the file to be defined above the place where they are used, this code will never work...how can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

recursive types:

```
type Foo = ...

and Bar = ...
```

so

```
[<Register ("MyUIImagePickerControllerDelegate")>]
type MyUIImagePickerControllerDelegate() as x = ...

and [<Register ("NewListing")>]
    NewListing (handle:IntPtr) as this = ...
```